# Does iOS 5 have a SSL security bug that got patched on iOS 6/7?

Tags: ios, security, ssl

Apple released iOS 7.0.6 and 6.1.6 to patch [a specific SSL/TLS security bug](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-1266).

I can't find anything official about iOS 5. Does iOS 5 have the same bug?

Please cite your answer.

Answer (score 11):

[ZDNet says](http://www.zdnet.com/when-will-apple-get-serious-about-security-7000026670/) :

> iOS 5 and Mac OS X 10.8 never had the bug

Answer (score 8):

Same manual test with [gotofail.com](http://www.gotofail.com)

- iOS 4.1 = Safe
- iOS 5.1.1 = Safe
- iOS 6.1.3 = Vulnerable
- iOS 7.0.4 + (SSLPatch) = Safe :)

According to [SSLPatch](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/02/fix-ssl-bug-without-upgrading-ios-7-0-6-ios-6-1-6.html) you are vulnerable from iOS 6.0 to iOS 6.1.5 and from iOS 7.0 to iOS 7.0.5.

Comment: last statement is somewhat incorrect since 6.1.6 has the fix

Answer (score 5):

You can visit [gotofail.com](https://gotofail.com) from Safari in iOS 5 and check yourself.

Comment: Is that site safe to go to?

Comment: Presumably, yes.  But for an even simpler test, try https://www.imperialviolet.org:1266/ (note the `https` if you type it in manually!)  It doesn't run any JavaScript; it's simply configured with example of a forged SSL certificate and will return plain text explaining the vulnerability if it is indeed present.  See https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html for the details.

Answer (score 5):

Jeffrey Grossman ([@Jeffrey903](https://twitter.com/Jeffrey903)) found that the bug came in with iOS 6, which means that iOS 5 and earlier builds are not affected:

> I have confirmed that the SSL vulnerability was introduced in iOS 6.0. It is not present in 5.1.1 and is in 6.0 ([22 Feb 2014 at 5:11 PM](https://twitter.com/Jeffrey903/status/437273379855667201))

He tested for the bug on a variety of earlier devices and versions:

> Not sure about 7.1 (device at office). So far I’ve tested 2.2, 2.2.1, 3.0, 3.1.3, 4.3.5, 5.1.1, 6.0, 6.1.3, 7.0.4, 7.0.6 ([22 Feb 2014 at 5:13 PM](https://twitter.com/Jeffrey903/status/437273890805809152))
>
> I tested the iOS SSL vulnerability using http://gotofail.com  on these 16 devices.  ([22 Feb 2014 at 6:36PM](https://twitter.com/Jeffrey903/status/437294783279939584))

I don’t know if he was the first to spot it, but I’m willing to trust his testing.